# Как хранить большой объем неструктурированных данных в БД?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, mongodb

Помогите определить стек для хранения относительно больших(не более 5-10мб) в базе данных. Либо выбрать что-то другое.

Есть сайт с объявлениями. Хочется сделать, чтобы у каждого из пользователей была возможность добавлять объявления в избранное.
Хранить объявления в избранном решено в базе данных. Пользователь отправляет на сервер запрос с ID объявлением. Сервер в свою очередь идентифицирует пользователя и записывает всё в таблицу.
Поскольку объявлений в избранном может быть много, то возникает вопрос, КАК хранить эти данные в таблице?

Думаю хранить в формате JSON, используя БД PostgreSQL или MongoDB. Однако, встает вопрос производительности, если этот JSON будет большим. 
Сами разработчики PostgreSQL говорят о том, что JSONB эффективен только, если его размер не больше 2 кб.

Относительно MongoDB, люди ругаются, что в продакшне может вести стебя крайне нестабильно и намного медленнее PostgreSQL.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как эффективнее хранить такие неструктурированные данные в базе данных, чтобы было быстро их оттуда доставать ?

Comment: Не удалять объявления из БД, хранить в избранном только их id.

Comment: @Kromster Объявления хранятся в отдельной таблице. А для избранного отдельная таблица, которая включает в себя : "id пользователя" : "данные"(в которых указываются id тех объявлений, которые он добавил).

Comment: А зачем такие сложности, если можно хранить структурировано как (id пользователя, id объявления)? В Postgresql с индексом по полю на паре миллиардов записей запросы выполняются очень быстро. Уверены, что количество пользователей у вас перевалит за 70 млн. и у каждого будет не менее 100 избранных объявлений, которые будут постоянно запрашивать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему вы это называете неструктурированными данными? Вполне структурированные данные, массив id объявлений.

Можно и писать просто в массив postgresql, тип данных `int[]` или `bigint[]` смотря что используете для идентификатора объявления. Если нужно искать, какие пользователи добавляли объявление в избранное - то добавить `gin` индекс.

Или не заниматься преждевременной оптимизацией и использовать нормальную форму М:М отношения с таблицей о двух полях: id пользователя, id объявления. Если с этим дорастёте до величин в сотни гигабайт в таблице - тогда уже думать что делать с этими всё ещё не большими объёмами данных.